# Undefined variable: id

Tags: php, variables, laravel

trying to make an edit function for my page but I keep getting unidentified variable: id

edit.blade.php

```
{{ Form::model($provider, array('route' => array('provider.edit', $provider->id))) }}
```

Route::get('account/edit')

```
$provider = Provider::find($id); 
return  View::make('provider.edit')->with(compact('provider'));
```

Comment: Where did you define $id?

Comment: Does this work instead?: `View::make('provider.edit',compact('provider'));`

Comment: `$id` needs to exist. That won't get passed in to your controller method with the route `Route::get('account/edit')` without some parameters such as `Route::get('account/edit/{id}')`

Comment: I believe you'd also need to name your route and make sure it has a controller and method assigned.  `Route::get('account/edit/{id}', array('as' => 'provider.edit', 'uses' => 'ProviderController@getEdit'));`